# Is it possible to create public folder mailbox via EWS using SOAP request?

Tags: outlook, office365, exchangewebservices

I cannot find any solution (SOAP request) to create public folder mailbox via EWS.

Comment: I’m afraid you could’t create public folder mailbox via EWS, because it only has two kinds of method in official documents. You could reference this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/collaboration/public-folders/create-public-folder-mailboxes?view=exchserver-2019

Answer (score 0):

No all public folder provisioning needs to be done using the either the EAC or the Exchange Management Shell cmldets. EWS is a client access API not a managed API so you can do thing a client could do (eg Create a New Folder, Set permission on that folder if you have rights, CRUD item actions) etc.

If you need to do public provisioning programatically then look at executing the cmdlets through managed code eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/ff326159(v%3Dexchg.140)

You should also consider the underlying infrastructure and how any why your creating secondary public folder Mailboxes (eg generally because of the size of the content). Eg the one thing you can't do in EWS is create a Public Folder on a particular Public Folder Mailbox etc that also need to be done via the EMS.